# How to disable/enable the textbox in some div on selecting the particular option value of dojo filtering select..?

Tags: html, dojo

how can i enable/disable particular text box on selecting the particular value from the filtering select of dojo..? eg if i select fresher then that textbox should disable.

Here my code:
this is my dojo select div

```
<div class="input select exp">
    <label>Total years of Experience</label>
    <select dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" name="sname" autocomplete="false"  id="yoe">
        <option value="Fresher">Fresher</option>
        <option value="1+">One year</option>
        <option value="2+">Two year</option>
        <option value="3+">Three Year</option>
    </select>
    <span class="error">required</span>
</div>
```

and in this div i need to disable or hide this textbox

```
<div class="input text">
    <label>Current Designation</label>
    <input type="text" value=""  dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" trim="true" id="sdd"/>
    <span class="error">required</span>
</div>
```

Kindly Reply Please help and any help will be appreciated more.

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML:

```
<SELECT onChange="adjust(this.value)>"

...

<DIV class="input text" id="inputtext">
```

and JavaScript:

```
function adjust(value) {
    if(value == ""Fresher) {
        document.getElementById('inputtext').style.display = 'none';
        ...
    } else if ...

}
```

Comment: Oh thanks a lot profMax u saved lot of time Thanks it works cool.